# Firebase insert item to specific position

Tags: python, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase. I am trying to insert new item to spesific position. [image]

Data structure is in the following image. Items are inserted with firebase generated keys and the order is important. I want to insert new item with new generated firebase key. For example; after "-KkoQbTvUe_TaKXV2N3f" and before "-KkoQcmtwNxluB0PQf1u". How can I do that?

Comment: On which platform, Android, JS or iOS? Please also share some code.

Comment: I am usign python for data insert. Actually I think platform doesnt matter. I just cannot find the way to insert to specific position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont find a generic way to do it. I just give numbers to items and sort them when I get them.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot insert a new unique key in beetween those mentioned keys because those key are generated according with the time and date of their adding. All those childrens are ordered by default in ascending order. What can you do in stead, is to use order functions provided by Firebase which are, `orderByChild`, `orderByKey` and `orderByValue`.

Hope it helps.